# Over writing ViewDataDictionary in ASP.NET MVC framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Instead of:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ViewData["foo"] = _repository.GetFoos().ToList();
    ViewData["bar"] = new string[] { "blah" };
    ViewData["baz"] = "";
    return View();
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Index(string baz)
{
    // Do stuff...

    ViewData["foo"] = _repository.GetFoos().ToList();
    ViewData["bar"] = new string[] { "blah" };
    ViewData["baz"] = baz;
    return View();
}
```

I was thinking about ways to reduce typo errors by making the ViewData a little more structured, without having to add (yet) another ViewModel class.  I came up with the following:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var foo = _repository.GetFoos().ToList();
    var bar = new string[] { "blah" };
    var baz = null;

    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary {
        {"foo", foo},
        {"bar", bar},
        {"baz", baz }
    };

    return View();
}

public ActionResult Index(string baz)
{
    var foo = _repository.GetFoos().ToList();
    var bar = new string[] { "blah" };
    var baz = null;

    // Do Stuff...

    ViewData = new ViewDataDictionary {
        {"foo", foo},
        {"bar", bar},
        {"baz", baz}
    };

    return View();
}
```

Is it a bad idea to overwrite the ViewData like that?  I'm pretty sure this wouldn't cause problems with RenderPartials, but would I no longer be able to call RenderAction in a view?

Comment: I would use the view model approach rather than either of what you propose here. A view model provides a layer of abstraction which pays dividends when you have to make modifications. Also, it allows you to strongly type the View which provides intellisense and is more self-documenting.

Aside from that I believe you can still call RenderAction. It would just be a case of how/what data you might want to pass to the RenderAction call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it a bad idea to overwrite the
>   ViewData like that?

No. It is not bad idea. But this is not common.

> I'm pretty sure
>   this wouldn't cause problems with
>   RenderPartials, but would I no longer
>   be able to call RenderAction in a
>   view?

You should be ok with all that.

But have a llok at your code without overwriting the ViewData and after.

You **did not eliminate any typo erro**r. You have the **same number of magic strings** in both cases.

So I would still **recommend to add a ViewModel**. For simplicity's sake just define your ViewModel within the controller class so you'll have it all in one place.

Comment: Hmm, that gives me another (probably crazy) idea.  I could set the controller as the model and use it's public instance variables in the view.  Which would be very rails-like.

Comment: Hmm, that is another option. I don't think it is too bad to do that. But it does violate SRP.